# Remove-Clear-the-selected-value-from-a-combobox-upon-changing

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have 2 combo boxes named; Street & Location inside a Power Canvas App.

Now I want to clear the selected value of the Location combo box when the Street combo box is changed.

How I can do so? I do not want to reset the value I want to clear it.

So it works on Edit as well as on New forms.

Answer (score 0):

Please reset the loaction combo box in the onchange attribute of the Street Combo box.

```
Reset(DataCardValue20)
```

[image]